# importing converted data using pandas

Tags: python, csv, pandas, linear-regression

I have a csv file that looks like this:

```
patient_id  age_in_years    CENSUS_REGION   URBAN_RURAL_STATUS  YEAR    MONTH   DAY_NUMBER_IN_MONTH race
11511   7   Northeast   Urban   2011    6   20  Other
9882613 73  South   Urban   2011    7   25  Unknown
32190339    49  West    Urban   2011    8   13  Caucasian
...
```

I have converted the categorical data in this file (e.g., race, census region, urban/rural status, etc.) into binary vector objects using the following method:

```
def URSTATUS_to_numeric(a):
if a == 'Urban':
    return [1, 0, 0]
if a == 'Rural':
    return [0, 1, 0]
if a == 'NULL':
    return [0, 0, 1]

df['URSTATUS_num'] = df['URBAN_RURAL_STATUS'].apply(URSTATUS_to_numeric)
```

I want to use these vectors for linear regression analysis but I'm unable to call them using the following the code:

```
def import_data(file_name):
 df = pd.read_csv(file_name).drop_duplicates()
 X_parameter = []
 #Y_parameter = []
 for alpha in zip(df['age_in_years']):
       X_parameter.append([float(alpha)])
       #Y_parameter.append(float(beta))
 return X_parameter#, Y_parameter

X = import_data(filename)

Y = df['URSTATUS_num']
```

The error that I'm getting is this:

```
TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're just iterating over that series to build a list of floats, you could instead use [astype](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html)(float).

It seems like you have some values in that column, though, that cannot be converted to float. For the sake of troubleshooting, maybe just try

```
for alpha in zip(df['age_in_years']):
    try:
       X_parameter.append([float(alpha)])
    except:
       print alpha
```

You should be able to replace that whole function using

```
X = pd.read_csv(file_name).drop_duplicates()['age_in_years'].astype(float)
```

Comment: this is just printing the said column. I want the code to take values from the required column in the csv file and the converted binary vector data and use it in regression.

Comment: Actually, the problem might be that you don't need zip(). It might be that you're trying to convert a tuple to a float rather than an int to a float. Maybe try:    'for alpha in df['age_in_years']:'

Comment: but that is the same as what you wrote in the answer.

Comment: Sorry, I edited it- but just try it without that zip, I suspect that's probably the issue.

Comment: it is not pulling any data from the csv file if i do that.

Comment: the problem now is that it won't treat `X` and `Y` as the same data type and hence won't carry out regression on it.

Comment: That seems like a distinct problem from the code you posted here? Maybe make a new question or some details about how you're doing the regression or what the error is